# Entity Framework providing column names as string variable

Tags: c#, string, entity, field

I'm looking for way to get something like this:

```
string _col1 = "first name";
string _name;
var query = from c in ctx.Customers select c;
_name = query.FirstOrDefault().[_name];
```

As far as I can see I can only get strongly typed field names but I would like to provide them as string variables.

Comment: you mean selecting the column or filtering by that column? In your example you are no using _col1 after assigning it. Please specify...

Comment: I have to put the column name based on the string value from list of strings so it's not for filtering

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if EF provides you with a way to get a property value based on the string name of the property, but you can use reflection.

```cs
string name = typeof(Customer)
    .GetProperty("first name")
    .GetValue(query.First(), null) as string;
```

I'm guessing the EF class you're dealing with is called `Customer`.

Comment: error when getting a collection of items instead of just one.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use reflection for this. If you are trying to filter by a dynamicly selected column, you can try something like this:

```
string propertyName
string keyword

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(YourType), "x");
Expression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
Expression target = Expression.Constant(keyword);
Expression containsMethod = Expression.Call(property, "Contains", null, target);
Expression<Func<YourType, bool>> lambda =
   Expression.Lambda<Func<YourType, bool>>(containsMethod, parameter);

var companies = repository.AsQueryable().Where(lambda);
```

I what you are trying to do is selecting a particular column, then you can use the same principle for generating the lamba expression and using it in the select (minus the condition)

```
var companies = repository.AsQueryable().Where(whatever).Select(lambda);
```

Comment: is there some reference for this?  what does "x" mean?

Comment: @Matt "x" is for the lambda expression, as in `x => x.Property` it could be anything. The reference, I got from a question I asked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246715/use-reflection-to-get-lambda-expression-from-property-name.

Answer (score 0):

For some kind of reason it won't work for me.

That's my similar working solution:

```
string name = null;

// Select the PropertyInfo of the column.
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = query.First().GetType().GetProperty("first name");

if (propertyInfo != null)
{
  try
  {
    // Select the content of the column.
    name = pi.GetValue(query.First(), null).ToString();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  { 
    // Continue with null-string.
  }
```

}